# Drawing image to root window in Xorg using Xcb causes it to cover other windows

Tags: rust, x11, xorg, xcb

I’m currently working on setting a background image in Xorg using XCB. I’ve managed to handle most of the problems, but I’m facing an issue where the images cover all the other windows

Here’s the code I’m using to set the background:

```
    let (conn, screen_num) = xcb::Connection::connect(None).unwrap();
    let setup = conn.get_setup();
    let screen = setup.roots().nth(screen_num as usize).unwrap();
    let (width, height) = (screen.width_in_pixels(), screen.height_in_pixels());

    let window = screen.root();

    let pixmap: x::Pixmap = conn.generate_id();
    conn.check_request(conn.send_request_checked(&x::CreatePixmap {
        depth: screen.root_depth(),
        pid: pixmap,
        drawable: x::Drawable::Window(window),
        width,
        height,
    }))?;

    let gc = conn.generate_id();
    conn.check_request(conn.send_request_checked(&x::CreateGc {
        cid: gc,
        drawable: x::Drawable::Pixmap(pixmap),
        value_list: &[],
    }))?;

    loop {
        let image = rx.recv()?; // Receive image from mpsc channel
        let image = resize_image(image, width as u32, height as u32)?; // This returns Vec<u8>
        conn.check_request(conn.send_request_checked(&x::PutImage {
            format: x::ImageFormat::ZPixmap,
            drawable: x::Drawable::Pixmap(pixmap),
            gc,
            width,
            height,
            dst_x: 0,
            dst_y: 0,
            left_pad: 0,
            depth: screen.root_depth(),
            data: &image,
        }))?;

        conn.check_request(conn.send_request_checked(&x::CopyArea {
            src_drawable: x::Drawable::Pixmap(pixmap),
            dst_drawable: x::Drawable::Window(window),
            gc,
            src_x: 0,
            src_y: 0,
            dst_x: 0,
            dst_y: 0,
            width,
            height,
        }))?;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't setting the wallpaper. You are drawing to the window. That's why your drawing covers other windows: You are drawing over them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the background image in Xorg with xcb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394304/how-can-i-set-the-background-image-in-xorg-with-xcb)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394304/how-can-i-set-the-background-image-in-xorg-with-xcb has some hints on how to set the wallpaper. The short version is: Set the "background pixmap" property of the root window and force a redraw. The long version: It's complicated.